# Fourth Homotopy Group of $S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration

I understand $\pi _{3}(S^2)$ by the Hopf Fibration which is the map

$p(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2-x_{3}^2-x_{4}^2, 2(x_1 x_4+x_2 x_3), 2(x_2 x_4-x_1 x_3))$.

These are disjoint circle in $\mathbb{R}^4$ mapped to points onto $S^2$. What is the map of $\pi _{4}(S^2)$?

I am trying to visualize $\pi _{4}(S^2)$ but I am having trouble. I have read [Visualize Fourth Homotopy Group of $S^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373078/visualize-fourth-homotopy-group-of-s2) but it is not coming to me. I think seeing a map like $p(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ will help.

Could someone please provide a map $p(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ for $\pi _{4}(S^2)$.

Comment: As in the answer to that other question, I think the Pontrjagin-Thom construction gives the best way of visualizing homotopy groups. The connection between homotopy classes $f\colon S^4\to S^3$ and framed manifolds is given by taking the preimage of a point of a map. This is well explained in Bredon's book.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip, thanks for the book reference I will check it out. I have seen the Pontryagin-Thom construction but it goes over my head. The post I linked in the question I believe have the construction but I am struggling to find the maps for them.